# Rewrite get parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, get

I'm trying to build a website upon different `$_GET` params.

I have

```
http://localhost/hundesiden/hunde/?race=labrador
```

I would like to be

```
http://localhost/hundesiden/hunde/labrador
```

and

```
http://localhost/hundesiden/hunde/?race=labrador&tilbehor=hundebur
```

to be

```
http://localhost/hundesiden/hunde/labrador/hundebur
```

I've tried different things in `.htaccess` - but can't accomblish what I want, can you help?

My `.htaccess` is this (doesn't work):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^hundesiden/hunde/([^/.]+)/?$ hundesiden/hunde/index.php?race=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Incorrect response? Nothing? The directive you posted should work for your first example (assuming `index.php` is the file that handles the request). Are `.htaccess` files enabled? etc.

Comment: Hi. Yea, nothing. The parameters just still shows up. It seems like .htaccess is enabled. I get an error 500 if I just enters garbage in it :)

Comment: Look at the server's [error.log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html) file to see what is broken.

Comment: "The parameters just still shows up." - ? What URL are you requesting? You should be requesting `/hundesiden/hunde/labrador` (no parameters) - that is what your directive is expecting.

Comment: If i request /hundesiden/hunde/labrador i get this 404 https://www.screencast.com/t/qVJq1XZXM